# Is there any build-in function in VBScript to trim a specific character?

Tags: string, vbscript, trim

There are functions in VBScript `Trim`, `LTrim` and `RTrim` to remove spaces from string beginning and/or ending. Is there any function to do that for any character? E.g.:

```
RTrim(" Hello, World!000", "0")     ' returns " Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). To get you started:

```
>> set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "0+$"
>> WScript.Echo r.Replace(" Hello, World! 00 a0000", "")
>>
 Hello, World! 00 a
>>
```

(the above is verbatim output of my REPL; so I would prefer to keep the format)

Answer (score 0):

No function exists built in, but you can write your own:

```
Function RTrimChar(byRef myString, byVal myChar)
    While Right(myString,1) = myChar
        myString = Left(myString, Len(myString)-1)
    End While
    RTrimChar = myString
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific function for this in VBScript, but you can use a regular expression replacement in a custom function:

```
Function CustomRTrim(str, c)
  If c = "" Then
    CustomRTrim = str
  Else
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = Left(c, 1) & "*$"
    CustomRTrim = re.Replace(str, "")
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Why should "*$" instead of "+$" be used?

Comment: AFAICS it wouldn't make a difference.